# SSL authentication between 2 nodejs servers

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, socket.io

I followed [this](http://www.gettingcirrius.com/2012/06/securing-nodejs-and-express-with-ssl.html) guide to secure my current express app with SSL client authentication (I'm using socket.io module for websockets). My app requires multiple node.js servers and I need to send messages between them.

Let A and B be two of that node.js servers and let's say that B wants to start a communication with A. Right now I'm simply using the socket.io-client module for opening a socket between them but this is not a valid option for me: anybody who knows A's URL could open a websocket and start sending messages to A. A needs in some way to verify that it can really rely on B.

Is it possible? I did not found any node.js module that meets my needs.

Comment: Have you considered using authorization with socket.io... http://stackoverflow.com/a/11702257/1135590

Comment: Thx I will have a look! But I wanted to use some PKI, both servers have their own certificates emitted by the same self-signed CA.

Comment: https://github.com/substack/secure-peer (released just today) creates encrypted peer-to-peer streams using public key cryptography and signing. Each side of the connection has the same kind of keys so it doesn't matter which side initiates the connection.